Get total session time for a user in Next Js
I am new to NextJs. I am using Next Auth for authentication, using credentials and an API written with Laravel (Sanctum). For gathering statistics about the user, I want to store the total logged-in time of the user in the database.
What is the best approach to this? Is there any easy way of doing so?

Why do you use both NextAuth and Laravel Sanctum? Wouldn't it be simpler to just use one authentication system? I think you are developing an API with Laravel, so why bring in NextAuth in the first place?

I know. I jumped on the project as is. The API is already protected by Sanctum and it is used by other apps as well.
Will get rid of Sanctum and just use Next Auth soon.

I'm a bit confused about your choice of using Next JS with Laravel. If you're developing a Laravel API, wouldn't it make more sense to use Sanctum instead of NextAuth?

The laravel app was already made and is protected with sanctum.

Got it. So, you don't need to use NextAuth. Just stick with using Laravel sanctum. Keep the sanctum and ditch the NextAuth. Handle the authentication from the backend in your Laravel app.
